# Linear gradient repeats

Tags: css, html

I have written the following html for a school website:

```
html {
   background-color: red;
   background-image: linear-gradient(red, Gray);
   background: red;
   background: linear-gradient(red, Gray);
   font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

It works but there is a problem: 
When I have to draw a full page gradient, it repeats downward. I do NOT want it torepeat. How can I fix this? I've searched the internet and my CSS + HTML book (which has a preview of HTML5).

---

Update: When I worked on the clubs page (shown below), the gradient was full and did not repeat. I used `<hr>` with the table and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<html>` is as tall as it needs to be by default, like any other element. Set its height explicitly, and you should be good to go:

```css
html {
    background-color: red;
    background-image: linear-gradient(red, gray);
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't CSS Automatically assume that the <html> tag would be 100%? I'm new to CSS :P